# How to change the labels of an area chart on Streamlit?

Tags: python, charts, data-science, streamlit

I have deployed an area chart using Streamlit for Python. Is it possible to change the labels for the axis X, as well as the labels for each data point plotted?

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
st.write(""" My area chart """)
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
st.area_chart(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let`s look on this example:

```
import numpy as np
chart_data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 3, 5]],
                          columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                          index=[1, 2, 3])
st.area_chart(chart_data)
```

[image]

For changing the x axis labels you can just change the index (it can be int/float or datetime for example). For changing the groups names you can change the columns names in your dataframe.

Comment: It worked. What I noticed and could be changed (if it does not exist yet) is the option to show the labels as string, since if I have a numeric label, Streamlit applies unwanted separators to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
st.write(""" My area chart """)
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
fig=px.area_chart(df)
fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_title="Description of x axis", yaxis_title="Description of y axis"
    )
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```